# Netbeans 8 support php mysql commands

Tags: php, mysql, netbeans

I have question about using mysql commands of php in netbeans 8. It is quite weird, but at work laptop i can type mys... and code complete suggests me commands like mysql_connect, or mysql_select_db and etc. But at home laptop it doesn't give me any suggest, just writes me "no suggest". I installed the same version at home, but it doesn't work. What addon or plugin should i connect?

Comment: Check your plugins tools->plugins , look if they differ among two pc's

Answer (score 0):

What solved it for me:

For some reason, you can only create a PHP project after Netbeans completes your PHP MySQL commands.